# How to validate multiple date format in form validation using regex_match in Codeigniter

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

How to validate multiple date format in codeigniter

This is my pattern:

```
/^([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\/([1-9]|1[0-2])\/202[0-5]$/
```

Codeigniter code:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mir_date', 'MIR Date', 'required|regex_match[/^([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\/([1-9]|1[0-2])\/202[0-5]$/]', [
            'required' => 'MIR Date',
            'regex_match' => 'Invalid MIR Date'
]);
```

Pattern should accept the following date format `d/m/yyyy`, `dd/mm/yyyy`, `dd/m/yyyy`, `d/mm/yyyy`

Comment: Are you sure your syntax is not off? `->->`? `regex_match[//.../]`? Try `$this->form_validation->set_rules('mir_date', 'MIR Date', 'required|regex_match[/^([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\/([1-9]|1[0-2])\/202[0-5]$/]', [` as the first line. If it does not work it is probably due to `|` and you either need to declare it as a separate function or define as an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use call back function in form validation Like below: -

```
set_rules('username', 'Username',   
'trim|required|xss_clean|callback__regex_check'); 

public function regex_check($str)
{
    if (preg_match("/^(?:'[A-Za-z](([\._\-][A-Za-z0-9])|[A-Za-z0-9])*[a-z0-9_]*')$/", $str))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('regex_check', 'The %s field is not valid!');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```